# Retrive a mail from gmail inbox for a particular subject

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

I have a scenario where I have to read a mail sent out by a **X person** with a specific subject, which i will be receiving on a daily basis.

Is there any **JAVA Gmail APi** provided by google to retrieve the recent mail that i have received.

And also is there a way to retrieve the mail for a **given date**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's a [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail) and it has a Java client library, you can check the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) to get used to it.

Now, for retrieving a list of mails you will need to use the [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) endpoint ( There's also a Java [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples_1) on how to use that endpoint). Answering your question about retrieving certain emails, you will need to use the `q` parameter and set the values there as if you would be searching an email in the gmail search bar. I will leave you an example that you can try using the ***Try this API***:

- [List emails from certain user and date](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22before%3AYYYY%2FMM%2FDD%2C%20from%3Amail%40domain%22%7D).

### Notice

You will only get the email's IDs, for getting more info about an email, you will have to use the [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) endpoint.